# How do I communicate to a LAMP's network from its own hosted website?

Tags: php, html, jquery, apache, lamp

Given two servers A and B, where A is exposed to the internet via a public URL, and B is just on the same network as the A; how do I make server A send actions to B?

One very simple example is to have A waking B.
Right now, I have a basic HTML page with a button that fires an AJAX request to a PHP file that has `shell_exec('wakeonlan ...')`, and another AJAX-to-PHP linked to a `div` that updates every 5 seconds to tell me if server B is On or Off.
I'm going a bit blind here since I'm not being able to find information on this kind of setup, and obviously I'd like to extend my functionality beyond a simple Wake-on-lan.

Is this possible with a LAMP server, or do I need something more complex?

Comment: What other actions do you want to send exactly? If server B is woken by the wakeonlan command, then once it's fully up and running, server A could send commands to it via whatever services and protocols B makes available. Exactly how you would do that depends on exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: @ADyson Virtually anything; if B is another Linux system, and C a Windows system, I'd like to be able to query either servers, execute programs or fetch files from C…

I'm sorry, am I asking for something too broad? I'd like to know how to communicate with servers that are local to A, but without depending on `shell_exec`, for instance. Which services can I rely on?

Comment: HTTP would probably make sense then - apply the same pattern you're already using with A. i.e. currently you make a http request to A which then runs shell_exec. In just the same way, A could make a HTTP request to B which could then run a SQL query or run a shell command or whatever you want. So if B has a webserver on it, you could do that. There are a dozen other ways you could potentially implement it I suppose but HTTP is a ready-made one which you are already familiar with.

Comment: @ADyson All right, but how do I request from A to B then with HTTP? If I use B's local IP address when making a request, won't the user's machine, who is outside A and B's network, be trying to perform that action to that IP instead?

Comment: No because you make the request from server A, using PHP. The server makes the request, not the browser. Think of Server A in the role of a relay or proxy server - you issue a command to server A from the browser, and server A then issues a command to server B - exactly as you're doing now with the wake on LAN command, except using http between A and B instead of the wake protocol

Comment: I was very confused on that subject. For whatever reason, I thought the local browser would make the requests itself. I should have a crash course on networking as a refresher. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@ADyson’s comments cleared me up on an confusion I was having relating to HTTP requests.

In sum, since it’s not the local browser that performs the actions on a website (I was thinking it was), I can use HTTP to communicate with the other servers without relying on an AJAX-to-PHP with a `shell_exec()` that triggers a `wakeonlan` command, which sounds way too complex to do what I want to do.